# How do I simplify for and if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, simplify

How do I simplify this? Thanks in advance :)

```py
a_list = []

for a, blah in enumerate(bunch_of_As.blahs):
    if a.name == "WHATEVER":
        for msg in a:
            if msg.type == "value 1":
                a_list.append(a)
            elif msg.type == "value 2":
                if msg.time != 0:
                    do_something(a)
                a_list.remove(a)
```

Comment: Looks simple enough and readable to me.

Comment: At `if a.name == "WHATEVER":` you use `a` as an object, and at `for msg in a:` you use `a` as an array. Is not there any mistakes?

Comment: @Yeheshuah what do you mean you use it "as an object"? Everything is an object in python. Including lists (which I presume is what you mean by "array"). Note, you can loop over any *iterable* object, they aren't using `a` as an array/list, they are using `a` as an iterable

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, maybe i misunderstanding, but 1) at `for a in bunch_of_As:` `a` is an iterable; 2) at `if a.name == "WHATEVER":` reading a property of `a`; 3) at `for msg in a:` using `a` as list. So, is not there a problem in step 3?

Comment: @Yeheshuah yes, you misunderstand, in `for a in bunch_of_As`, `a` **is not the iterable**. It is merely part of the "target list" of the for-statement target, basically just a regular variable that will take whatever the iterator spits out. `bunch_of_As` is the *iterable*, i.e. the *thing being iterated over*. You ca iterate over *anything* that implements the iterator/iterable protocol, so there can definitely be objects that have a `.name` attribute along with being valid iterables, i.e. `for x in iterable:` doesn't raise a type error. There is no such thing as "using something as a list".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga、sorry, I mistook "iterable" wording. Exactly, I was pointing to "anything that implements the iterator/iterable protocol". @JULS did not provide type of bunch_of_As's elements, so I bit got lost.

Comment: @Yeheshuah I did switch it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to simplify this, because your add and remove the a element on the a_list unnecesary a lot of times

```
for a in bunch_of_As:
    if a.name == "WHATEVER":
        counter1 = 0
        counter2 = 0
        for msg in a:
            if msg.type == "value 1":
               counter1 += 1
            elif msg.type == "value 2":
               counter1 += -1
               if msg.time != 0:
                  counter2 += 1
       for n in range(counter1):
           a_list.append(a)

       for n in range(counter2):
           do_something(a)
```

Only i have two question or hypo, 
i suppose that the number of "value 1" => (more or equal) num "value 2"
and the do_something(a) effect on a is null

Its clearly that are more lines of codes, but reduces the unnecessary proccess of the append remove

Comment: Of course this assumes `do_something` doesn't have any crazy side effects